# c# inheriting generic collection and serialization…

Tags: c#, inheritance, xml-serialization, collections, generics

with reference to [c# inheriting generic collection and serialization…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666054/c-inheriting-generic-collection-and-serialization/2272825) question

If you are providing a paged collection it is useful to pass back the total available so the client can set up they paging control. Does anyone know a nice way to achieve?

Also why is this "By Design" seems pointless.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

See [PagedList](http://www.squaredroot.com/2009/06/15/return-of-the-pagedlist/) for example.

Comment: Thanks mate, looks interesting.