# WCF Return Data is Missing Data When Subclassing a List<T>

Tags: wcf, collections, return-value, subclass, message

I am sharing contract between my client and server (not using generated proxies). Here is the contract (note I have also tried ObservableCollection):

```
public class MyList : List<MyItem> {
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public MyList() { }
}
```

The Total is still set when the EndMyOperation async callback method is called on the server. However, when I look at the value on the client the Total is gone (set to 0). The trace clearly shows that the additional attribute is not being passed. Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening?

```
<MessageLogTraceRecord>
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/MyOperation</Action>
    <ActivityId CorrelationId="d2872ac2-685e-4f94-b516-aaba4effa463" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">695d611f-2b3d-48ca-80b8-7ceae4fd423f</ActivityId>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
      <MyOperationResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <MyOperationResult xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyDataContract" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
          <d4p1:MyItem>
            <d4p1:MyId>1</d4p1:MyId>
          </d4p1:MyItem>
          <d4p1:MyItem>
            <d4p1:MyId>12</d4p1:MyId>
          </d4p1:MyItem>
        </MyOperationResult>
      </MyOperationResponse>
    </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>
</MessageLogTraceRecord>
```

Just to clarify I know I can solve the issue, by not subclassing and doing something like below. Rather I am trying to understand why the above behavior happens.

```
public class MyPagedList<T> { 
    public int Total { get; set; } 
    public List<T> MyList { get; set; }
    public MyPagedList() { MyList = new List<T>(); }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the actual datacontract?  Have you correctly placed the DataMember attribute above the properties you wish to have serialized?

Comment: @MattC - The MyList class is the datacontract. There is no need to place attributes on the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `MyItem` `[Serializable]`? Or rather are the fields on `MyItem` Serializable?

Or could this be your problem: [inheriting-generic-collection-and-serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666054/c-inheriting-generic-collection-and-serialization)

Comment: The are not marked explicitly as such, but yes they are serializable. Your link is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.