# IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings not persisting all properties

Tags: serialization, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize this class to Windows Phone ApplicationSettings, but for some reason, only the `Items` are persisted and not the `Title` or `LastChanged` properties. Any ideas as to why are appreciated!

Class:

```
public class VehicleCollection : ObservableCollection<Vehicle>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastChanged { get; set; }

    public bool HasNoItems { get { return Items.Count == 0; } }

    public VehicleCollection() { }
    public VehicleCollection(string title, DateTime lastChanged)
    {
        Title = title;
        LastChanged = lastChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("HasNoItems"));
    }
}
```

Persist logic:

```
    public static bool SavePersistent(string key, object value)
    {
        if (null == value)
            return false;

        var store = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        if (store.Contains(key))
            store[key] = value;
        else
            store.Add(key, value);

        store.Save();
        return true;
    }

    public static T LoadPersistent<T>(string key)
    {
        var store = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        if (!store.Contains(key))
            return default(T);

        return (T)store[key];
    }
```

---

Edit: I've created a sample project where the behavior is evident. http://www.fileswap.com/dl/2ar0ygF8w7/

1. Run the app and watch the static data being created
2. Press "save data" to save to IsolatedStorage
3. Close and re-run the app
4. Watch the title for both collections disappear, as they were not persisted

Comment: As weird as this may sound, this behavior is by design. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666054/c-sharp-inheriting-generic-collection-and-serialization   It's about `XmlSerializer` but it also applies to `DataContractSerializer` (which is used internally by `IsolatedStorageSettings`)

Comment: Thanks KooKiz, that seems to be the culprit. Still weird, but I guess I'll have to work around it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is the problem arises from the fact that you inherit your VehicleCollection class from ObservableCollection and that serialization and deserialization have a piece of code in them like 'if object is ObservableCollection'. I've tried your sample solution and the getter of the members is simply not called on serialization, nor is the setter called on deserialization.

The solution would be to refactor your VehicleCollection class like this:

```
  public class VehicleCollection 
  {
      public string Title { get; set; }
      public DateTime LastChanged { get; set; }

      public bool HasNoItems { get { return Items.Count == 0; } }

      public VehicleCollection() 
      { 
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Vehicle>()
      }
      public VehicleCollection(string title, DateTime lastChanged) :this()
      {
          Title = title;
          LastChanged = lastChanged;
      }

      public ObservableCollection<Vehicle> Items

  }
```

The bad thing of course is that then VehicleCollection needs to implement INotitifyPropertyChanged to get the HasNoItems to fire. Anyway - if I change it this way in your sample solution it works.

Answer (score 0):

[This is not directly an answer to your question, but is a solution.]

Chances are you are already using JSON.NET or something similar. What about using that to serialize the object into a string, then save the string?

Using JSON.NET, this would change your code to:

```
        public static bool SavePersistent(string key, object value)
    {
        if (null == value)
            return false;

        value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        var store = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        if (store.Contains(key))
            store[key] = value;
        else
            store.Add(key, value);

        store.Save();
        return true;
    }

    public static T LoadPersistent<T>(string key)
    {
        var store = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        if (!store.Contains(key))
            return default(T);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>((string)store[key]);
    }
```

And it will probably give you better performance anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, tried it, but it gives me the same result somehow.